# backtest stats suggest that my stop loss and take profits are not working but I can't figure out why

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am having some trouble setting a stop loss and a target.  With the below code, the trade should stop out if it drops 2% from entry and should exit with a take profit at 5%.  However in the strategy tester the average winning trade is 12.91% and the average losing trade is 5.64% - suggesting that the stops and take profits aren't working properly.

I've checked the price values using a label for debugging and they are correct.

The strategy tester settings have 'recalculate after order is filled' selected.

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong..?

```
// Stop %
initialStopPerc = 0.02 // 2% initial Stop

// Targets %
longTarget = 0.05 // 5% target
shortTarget = 0.05 // 5% target

longInitialStopPrice = 0.0
shortInitialStopPrice = 0.0
longTargetValue = 0.0
shortTargetValue = 0.0

if (longCondition and strategy.position_size <= 0)
  
    // Determine initial stop loss  prices
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    longInitialStopPrice := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - initialStopPerc)
    longTargetValue := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + trailStopStartsPerc)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Long", limit=longTargetValue, stop=longInitialStopPrice)


if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    shortInitialStopPrice := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + initialStopPerc)
    shortTargetValue := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - trailStopStartsPerc)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Short", limit=shortTargetValue, stop=shortInitialStopPrice)
```

I've tried changing the code to move the exit into a less strict conditional argument based on another answer on stackoverflow.  All this does is change the percentages so that the average winning and losing trades become less than the limit order and stop loss respectively - but still with maximum trades way beyond.  That code looks like:

```
// Stop %
initialStopPerc = 0.02 // 5% initial Stop

// Targets %
longTarget = 0.05 // 5% target
shortTarget = 0.05 // 3% target


var longInitialStopPrice = 0.0
var shortInitialStopPrice = 0.0
var longTargetValue = 0.0
var shortTargetValue = 0.0  

if (longCondition and strategy.position_size <= 0)
  
    // Determine initial stop loss  prices
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    longInitialStopPrice := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - initialStopPerc)
    longTargetValue := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + trailStopStartsPerc)

if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    shortInitialStopPrice := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + initialStopPerc)
    shortTargetValue := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - trailStopStartsPerc)
    

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Long", limit=longTargetValue, stop=longInitialStopPrice)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Short", limit=shortTargetValue, stop=shortInitialStopPrice)
```